# Zend Custom Route if no match found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I have a ZF app with several modules as this: ( as usual )

```
root\
    \application\
                \default
                \items
                \me
                   \controllers
                   \views
```

The application uses the default routing like `/module/controller/action`;

What I want is this: if no match has been found for the default Zend Routing (no action / controller / module has been found ) then route to a **desired path** with the url endpoint spitted into parameters.

For example:

- `mydomain.lh/me` -> will match the module `me`, controller `index`, action `index` ( as default )
- `mydomain.lh/my_category_name` -> will match the module `items`, controller `index`, action `index`, `params`: category => my_category_name -> using the **desired path** route

  - no `my_category_name` module exists to match against

I have tried with this, into bootstrap.php:

```
 public function _initRoutes ()
{
    $router = $this->_front->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default

    $router->addRoute(
        'cat-item',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:category',
                                         array(
                                            'module' => 'items',
                                            'controller' => 'index',
                                            'action' => 'index'))
    );
}
```

Witch points to the correct location ( I know because I var_dump -ed the request url into the `items/index/index` action and the expected url and parameters were there, but if I do not do `var_dump(something);exit;` into the action, a blank page is served.

- no output is made but also no error is generated, the request status is 200 - OK

Can anybody have a suggestion  ?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can `var_dump` in the action and you have the appropriately named/placed view-script for that action, then a blank page often signifies that an error occurred but you have errors suppressed. Modifying your `application/configs/application.ini` to show those errors - `phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1`, `phpSettings.display_errors = 1`, and `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1`) often exposes the problem.

Comment: No, there is no error. If I remove the routing rule, then all things are back to normal. 

- when I add this rule, no other action can be accessed anymore, everithing is redirected to the desired path, witch also is a problem.

Comment: Aaah, well that's a different issue. No surprise that this route is picking up so many urls, including the default; it's very general. Maybe trap in the error controller, checking for the 404 condition and then either redirecting or setting the request params to your required (module, controller, action) triplet and setting the request as not dispatched.

Comment: Yes, currently this is the workaround for this, I am using an _forward when an 404 error is thrown on the error controller.
I was hoping that it can be done with routers - witch should be an elegant solution.